# Using an ENV variable with the url in a link_to in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the URL for the ISSUES in an environment variable. I have an image, that when clicked is supposed to direct one to that URL. I've read the documentation on the `link_to` tag and have tried several variations to no avail.  Here is what I have:

```
<%= link_to "{<%= ENV["ISSUES_SERVER"] %>}" do %>
   <%= image_tag("/assets/bug.gif", :size => "27x25" %>
<% end %>
```

How do I get the `ENV["ISSUES_SERVER"]` as the URL for the `link_to`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried the most obvious, which I had overlooked as it looked too easy.  It looked like it need something surrounding it at first.

```
<%= link_to ENV["ISSUES_SERVER"],  :target => "_blank" do %>
   <%= image_tag("/assets/bug.gif", :size => "27x25") %>
<% end %>
```

This worked quite well.  I have noticed that I can no longer have the image change its' highlighting as I mouse over it after these changes.  I can live with that, I suppose.